# append the date time to log file when a new day arrive

Tags: log4j

I am currently using the following log4j properties for my log file. But the problem is , if there is no activity for that particular class, the log file name still becomes `mylogfile.log` whether it is created at 20 April, 2013.

For Me, I have another process checking the log file name extension example `mylogfile.log.2013-04-24`  and process (yesterday's log file) every morning. So now there is no activity and the log file created at 20 Apirl, 2013 still with the name `mylogfile.log` instead of `mylogfile.log.2013-04-24`.

How can I set log4j.properties to make a log file to add date when a new day has started.
Actually, I am using DailyRollingFileAppender though.

Here is my current setting.

```
log4j.logger.MyLog=DEBUG, mylog

log4j.appender.mylog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.mylog.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.mylog.File=${myproject.log.dir}/mylogfile.log
log4j.appender.mylog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.mylog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mylog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss},%m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in appender does not support this I believe (not in Log4J 1.2 at least)

However there are other external appenders you can look into, for example, TimeAndSizeRollingAppender in http://www.simonsite.org.uk/, for which file rolling is done when time arrived instead of when first log event is dispatched.